# Did Muhammad (pbuh) ever go to Jerusalem to spread the word of Allah?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, prophet-isa, bible, bani-israel

I think I found another prophecy of Muhammad (pbuh) in Isaiah 40. Chapter 40 of the Book of Isaiah (from the Hebrew Bible) is called "Comfort for God's People". It starts like this:

```
Comfort, comfort my people,
    says your God.
 Speak tenderly to Jerusalem,
    and proclaim to her
that her hard service has been completed,
    that her sin has been paid for,
that she has received from the Lord’s hand
    double for all her sins.
```

The Greek translation of these verses are:

```
parakaleíte parakaleíte tón laón mou légei o theós

iereís lalísate eis tín kardían Ierousalim parakalésate aftín óti eplísthi i tapeínosis aftís lélytai aftís i amartía óti edéxato ek cheirós kyríou diplá tá amartímata aftís
```

I'm sure you've noticed that "Comfort" translates to "Parakaleíte" in Greek. And according to John 16:7, Jesus (pbuh) said:

```
"Nevertheless, I tell you the truth; 
it is expedient for you that I go away: 
for if I go not away, the Comforter will not come unto you; 
but if I depart, I will send him unto you"
```

Now there are 2 things to consider here:

1) Jesus said "**the** Comforter", not "a Comforter". This means that it is a Comforter that the people of Israel already knew about (from Isaiah 40)

2) In the Greek translation of this verse, "the Comforter" is translated to "Paracletos". This word is similar to "Parakaleíte" from Isaiah 40.

3) The verse says that the Comforter will come only after Jesus (pbuh) goes away

So Isaiah 40 could be talking about Muhammad (pbuh).

**But my question is, did Muhammad (pbuh) ever go to Jerusalem to spread the word of Allah?** Because Isaiah 40 is telling this "Comforter" to "*bring the good news to Jerusalem*" and *say to the towns of Judah "Here is your God!"* (verse 9).

Here's the link to Isaiah 40: https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+40

Here's the link to the Greek translation of Isaiah 40: https://www.blueletterbible.org/lxx/isa/40/1/s_719001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far my knowledge go, that refers to Jesus A.S.

Nabi Isaiah A.S. is telling the people of the upcoming prophet which is the mesiah for the bani israel. To start a new ruling state of the world from the holy land , jerusalem.

Answer (score 0):

The Messenger of Allah () never went to that place again -assuming his travel in company of his uncle for trading took him to this place- after becoming a Prophet() except for the event of Isra'!
And Jerusalem became part of the Muslim Empire at the time of 'Omar ibn al-Khattab (). So expect for this situation Mohammad never left the Arabic Peninsula.